# Apex unit tests taking very long time to execute inside Salesforce

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've written several simple Apex unit tests and I'm trying to run them through Salesforce, so:

```
Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution > Select Test... > Run
```

The tests are passing, the code is fine.

But quite regularly I'm finding the tests just don't run at all. I select a test and hit `run` and all I get is the Queued icon next to my test and the following message when I click on the test:

```
Selected job is not yet complete.
```

Sometimes the test kicks off after a few minutes and sometimes it's up to an hour or more and once the test starts it only takes a few seconds to complete.

It must be a problem with Salesforce.

Has anyone else encountered this and is there a solution?

Comment: There is a limit on test runs or APIs. Have you checked that?

Comment: Maximum number of test classes that can be queued per 24-hour period (production organizations other than Developer Edition)5 The greater of 500 or 10 multiplied by the number of test classes in the organization

Comment: Maximum number of test classes that can be queued per 24-hour period (sandbox and Developer Edition organizations)5 The greater of 500 or 20 multiplied by the number of test classes in the organization

Comment: I recommend adding some System.debug() statements to your code so you can use the log files to see what parts of the code are running.

Comment: Have you checked trust.salesforce.com to see what the status is of your instance? Its possible your instance is having issues. When an instance is having issues, sandboxes and test classes go to the bottom of the priority list to keep production instances up and running.

Comment: I've got similiar problem (EU region). Tests were queued forever and it wasn't related to complexity of test. I also tried running tests from developer console with no luck.  I suggest you using MavensMate. I am using it and it runs tests considerably faster. MM is using API to run test and they aren't queued at all.

Comment: @mischczu ok this really seems to be doing the trick! Much appreciated. If you would like to throw it into an answer, I'll accept it as an alternative to running the tests in Salesforce.

Comment: I find the delay to be so incredibly annoying. Nothings going on and sometimes it just sits and sits for no apparent reason. You are trying to complete a project and salesforce appears to be doing nothing including running the tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got similiar problem (EU region). Tests were queued forever and it wasn't related to complexity of test. I also tried running tests from developer console with no luck. I suggest you using MavensMate. I am using it and it runs tests considerably faster. MM is using API to run test and they aren't queued at all